# Changes to activity_main.xml does nothing

Tags: android, android-studio

Changes made to one of my layout-files does nothing. Somehow Android Studio compiles the project with an old version of the layout-file. I tried "Invalidate Caches and restart" , didn't help.

How is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and then a rebuild?

Comment: No, thank you so much! Feel pretty stupid now.

Comment: You're welcome! If that solved your problem, I'll add it as an answer so future viewers can easily see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens, you should typically clean and then rebuild the project by using the options in the `Build` menu.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, check to make sure you're actually editing the right XML file.  (I can't believe it took me this long to realize why I was having issues!)